# appending the items in one array to the end of another in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

If I have two arrays

```
unsigned char buffer[80];
unsigned char data[3]

// data array will always hold hex values
data[] = {0x00, 0xEB, 0xFF}
```

If I wanted to keep updating the buffer array by appending the elements of data[] (which will always be hex values) on to the end of it what would be the best way to do this since I know what the max size of the buffer array can be? Also, what would need to change if I did not know what the max size of the buffer array would be and need to update that as I'm adding to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of the number of bytes already in the `buffer` array. It starts out at zero, and for every byte you append you increase this counter by one. This means that not only do you know the number of bytes in the array, the counter is also the the next position to add to.

So if the counter is zero, then you set `buffer[0]` and increase the counter to one. Then to append the next byte you set `buffer[1]` and increase the counter to two, etc.

---

To continually append the `data` array in a loop, use `memcpy` and increase the counter by the number of items in `data`:

```
size_t count = 0;  /* Counter starts out at zero */

/* Append the `data` array five times */
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    /* Use of `sizeof` here assumes that `data` is a proper array and not a pointer */
    memcpy(&buffer[count], data, sizeof(data));

    /* Increase counter */
    count += sizeof(data);
}
```

Note: The code assumes that both `buffer` and `data` are arrays of `char` (or other 8-bit types).

Also take care that you don't write beyond the bounds of the `buffer`.

Comment: That is how I am actually initially filling the buffer with the first set of values returned in data. But if the data[] is actually in a loop and those values are changing and I want to keep adding those new values to buffer what would be the equivalent to something like buffer.AddRange(data) which is found in C#?

Comment: I think I sort of see what you are saying though would you be able to show a quick example?

Comment: @Stavros_S Added simple example

Comment: Appreciate the sample! Doesn't memccpy take 4 arguments though?

Comment: scratch that you did memcpy not memccpy

Comment: Would this not work if I took it out of that for loop?

Comment: @Stavros_S If you don't have a loop, you will only append once.

Comment: that is what I thought for some reason I cannot seem to get the method you should above to produce anything for me